# why can android's uiautomator not find element within a ListView when orientation is in portrait?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am using uiautomator to select text from a ListView. In landscape mode, it scrolls through the list and finds the item fine; however, in portrait mode, it cannot find the text. The ListView is fully visible in portrait mode so scrolling is not required but this should't cause an error should it?

```
UiScrollable listView = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(
        true).className("android.widget.ListView"));

UiObject button1 = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
.className(android.widget.CheckedTextView.class.getName()),
        "Text");

button1.click();
```

Error is as follows:

```
com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException: for text= "Text"
at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiCollection.getChildByText(UiCollection.java:111)
at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.getChildByText(UiScrollable.java:189)
at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable.getChildByText(UiScrollable.java:166)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure that in your button inside text "Text", use better getChildByInstance() method

Comment: The only issue with that is that the instance relates to what is initially visible so, while that will work fine for me in portrait mode it will not in  landscape, as not all elements are visible. So if the first item visible is the third item for example, that will be the 1st instance, missing the others. I could swipe to the top first; however, and then use instance. I will try that, thanks for the help!

Comment: The getChildByInstance does not work either when the whole list is visible so the issue seems to be a UiScrollable issue. I can use a workaround but it should not behave like this either way